# Simple-cdd keyring addition

Tags: debian, gpg, preseed

I'm looking to add a personal key for an apt repo to a netinstall disc which would require end users to not have to install it. I'm using simple-cdd to generate the build, so wrapping it into a .deb would be an option. But would copying the /etc/apt/trusted.gpg into a .deb be a bad idea? Would there be breakage? I'd like to just have the key installed properly. But preseeding late commands don't seem to have proper access to apt-key/keyring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer in the form of preseeding the netinstall.

```
d-i apt-setup/local0/repository string http://repo.url/ dist main
d-i apt-setup/local0/source boolean true
d-i apt-setup/local0/key string http://key.url/
```

The above three preseed commands will respectively perform the following tasks: add the repository to sources.list automatically, include an entry for source packages, and add the key.

[source (statik github)](https://gist.github.com/981961/233b25b6a36019fab5319a272ccd6ab7173b9dbe#file-full_preseed-cfg)